# Setting nested loop value returns error "e.replace is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse poems so that each line is an item in the tileset array, and each word is an item within that array (2 levels). I want each word to be in a span, and (later) each new line to have a break between.

I run into problems when I loop through to change the value of individual word (tileset[a][b]) to be wrapped in a span.

Here is the code:

```
function tilify (){
  var tiletext = $(".tile-set").html().trim().replace("<br>","  ").replace(/ +(?= )/g,"  "); // trimming whitespace and regulating newline format to a double-space
  tileset = tiletext.split("  "); // creating an array of lines
  for (a in tileset) {
    tileset[a] = tileset[a].split(" "); // creating a nested array of words
    for (b in tileset[a]) {
      tileset[a][b] = "<span class='tile'>" + tileset[a][b] + "</span>";  // returns error
    };
  };
  $(".tile-set").html(tileset);
}

tilify();
```

The error returned is `Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function`

I have tried several loop syntaxes. I've also tried getting rid of the `.replace` method that I use just in case. It works if I wrap elements of the first array in the span tags, but not the second.

I have jquery and jqueryUI running.

Again this is the block I'm having trouble with:

```
for (b in tileset[a]) {
  tileset[a][b] = "<span class='tile'>" + tileset[a][b] + "</span>";  // returns error
};
```

Here is the body of the HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <p class='tile-set'>
    The boot is famous to the earth,
    more famous than the dress shoe,
    which is famous only to floors.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: could you post the html as well ?

Comment: Just edited it to include the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Your code is breaking on the `$(".tile-set").html(tileset);` line because the $.html() can't handle a nested array. It's looking for an array of strings. If you want to include everything in one element, you'll need another for loop and then concat the whole thing like this: 

`for(a in tileset) {
  $(".tile-set").html($(".tile-set").html()+tileset[a]);
  }`

Comment: I think you have the right idea about the problem, but your code isn't going to work right. `$(".tile-set").html` isn't going to be useful! You'll want `$('.tile-set').forEach()` or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this do what you want?

```
function tilify (){
    var tiletext = $(".tile-set").html().trim().replace("<br>","  ").replace(/ +(?= )/g,"  "); // trimming whitespace and regulating newline format to a double-space
    tileset = tiletext.split("  "); // creating an array of lines
    $(".tile-set").html(""); // Set the html to be an empty string so we can concatenate
    for (a in tileset) {
        tileset[a] = tileset[a].split(" "); // creating a nested array of words
        for (b in tileset[a]) {
            $(".tile-set").html( $(".tile-set").html() + "<span class='tile'>" + tileset[a][b] + "</span>" );
        };
      };
    }

    tilify();
}
```

You get this output `Thebootisfamoustotheearth, morefamousthanthedressshoe, whichisfamousonlytofloors` but you can modify the `<span></span>` tags to work the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was trying to pass a nested array into the `.html()` method (thanks Phil). I passed the text into a `tilesetBody` variable and used that instead.

```
function tilify () {
  var tiletext = $(".tile-set").html().trim().replace("<br>","  ").replace(/ +(?= )/g,"  ").replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\./g,"").replace(/\;/g,"");
  var tilesetBody = "";
  tileset = tiletext.split("  ");

  for (a in tileset) {
    tileset[a] = tileset[a].split(" ");
    for (b in tileset[a]) {
      if (tileset[a][b] != "") {
        tileset[a][b] = "<span class='tile'>" + tileset[a][b] + "</span> ";
        tilesetBody += tileset[a][b];
      }
    };
    tilesetBody += "<br>";
  };

  $(".tile-set").html(tilesetBody);
}
```